# How to get captions to display in Galleria (for Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, image, web-part-gallery

I'm using this solution to create image galleries in a SP 2013 Online site:
http://www.getinthesky.com/2014/04/sharepoint-image-gallery-doesnt-suck/

The script uses the image alt/title tag to display captions for an image. I modified this line to pull in the "caption", but it displays as "undefined" which usually means the field is not in the view:

```
jQuery("#galleria").append("<img src='" + jQuery(this).attr("href")
+ "' alt='" + jQuery(this).attr("alt") +  "' /> ");
```

In theory the picture library's description field is supposed to populate the alt tag but I'm not sure if it does. Anyone have any light they could shed on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#galleria").append("<img src='" + jQuery(this).attr("href") + "' alt='" + jQuery(this).attr("href").substring((jQuery(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf('/'))+1, jQuery(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf('.')) +  "' />");
```

A little rough but this did work for me. forgot to add that this will grab the file name and display it in the alt but I'm sure you can modify it to work for you.

Comment: Thankyou - that does get the file name but I think the "undefined" caption issue lies with Sharepoint not finding the description field in the view. Looking at the native library, the image alt is indeed the description field. But it doesn't render using galleria.

Answer (score 0):

you can try my code.

// Some advise: Keep folders and images seperate. The makes for the best views

```
  jQuery('#onetidDoclibViewTbl0 a.ms-listlink:not([onmousedown^="javascript"])').each(function() {
      var thumbnailpath = '/' + jQuery(this).attr("href").substring(1, jQuery(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + 
   "_w/" + jQuery(this).attr("href").substring(jQuery(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf('/') + 1, 
  jQuery(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf('.')) + "_" + 
  jQuery(this).attr("href").substring(jQuery(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf('.') + 1) + ".jpg";  
  var imagepath = jQuery(this).attr("href");

  var ImageStructure = '<a href="'+jQuery(this).attr("href")+'"><img alt="' +jQuery(this).attr("href")+'" src="' + thumbnailpath + '" data-image="' + imagepath + '" style="display:none"></a>'; 
  jQuery("#galleria").append(ImageStructure); });
```